# Turning two string into a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, nokogiri

Right now, I have the following:

```
<% @headlines.css('a').each do | headline | %>
   <%= headline.text %>
<% end %>

<% @top_stories.css('a').each do | top_story | %>
   <%= top_story.text %>
<% end %>
```

([Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) code)

Which outputs this:

```
"
    Heat vs. Bulls, Lakers vs. Clippers on opening night

    Free Agent Tracker

    Player movement
"

"

"
     Heat-Bulls, Lakers-Clippers on opening night 

     Closer look at sked 

     Most intriguing 

     Official release 

     Suns' Beasley arrested for suspected drugs 
"
```

I would like to turn those two strings into a ruby hash. Something like this:

```
{:headlines => ['Kobe ahead of schedule'], etc etc, :top_stories: ['Ex-Lebron pest Stevenson pinning to join Heat', etc etc] }
```

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= hash_res %>, <%= headline %> = {}, ''
<% @headlines.css('a').each do | headline | %>
    <%= headline %> << <%= headline.text %>
<% end %>
<%= head_res[:headlines] %> = headline

# Do the same thing for the below
<% @top_stories.css('a').each do | top_story | %>
    <%= top_story.text %>
<% end %>
```